# RESIN: Create Multiple Properties files and Make Resin Locate and Use Them

Tags: properties-file, resin

After reviewing the Resin documentation, it mostly just talks about using only one properties files.

I know resin.xml can reference multiple properties files like this:

**< resin:properties path="${__DIR__}/custom.properties" optional="true"/>**

Is there a way to replace the standard properties file (i.e.resin.properties) with multiple other properties files and **most importantly** place them somewhere else other than standard ${RESIN_HOME}/conf directory?

With what arguments can I run Resin so that it can locate those custom properties files?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

resin:properties@path can be a full path as so:

```
path="/etc/resin/resin.properties"
```

Alternatively, Resin can resolve -D arguments with ${} expression.

```
< resin:properties path="${location}/custom.properties" optional="true"/>
```

e.g.

```
bin/resin.sh -Dlocation=/custom/resin start
```

resin.xml:

```
< resin:properties path="${location}/custom.properties" optional="true"/>
< resin:properties path="${location}/custom2.properties" optional="true"/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Seems like -D define is a better option here.

Comment: what is `optional="true"` attribute for?